# Code to show categories on Product page causing 503 if product isn't in a category

Tags: php, magento

I'm using the code below to show the categories that any product belongs to, The site is for computers, and it shows what systems(categories) the parts work with. The issue I have is that the site is huge, and I'm cleaning it up, but until I can go through the thousands of products I end up with a wierd looking page if the product isn't in a category. I was thinking I need to include an if/else or something or in another way close the php call. I'm not the php guru AT ALL.

```
<?php
        $currentCatIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
        $categoryCollection = 
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('url')
                             ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', 
$currentCatIds)
                             ->addIsActiveFilter();
    ?>
<ul><?php foreach($categoryCollection as $cat){ ?>
    <li><a href="<?php $cat->getUrl();?>"><?php echo $cat->getName(); } ?></a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: basically I need this to stop throwing an error if there's no results

Comment: seems the answer was already in this version of the code, not the one I was using.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39340166/magento-show-categories-a-product-is-in