# Filtering non active categories in magento

Tags: php, magento

So I'm using this code to display the categories that any product on my website is included in. The issue is that I'm using some categories as placeholders to show 'featured products' I wanted to try to filter these out.

This is Magento 1.9.1.0 on PHP 5.6.30

```
<ul class="listfix">
<?php $categories = $_product->getCategoryIds(); ?>
<?php foreach($categories as $k => $_category_id):
 ?>
<?php $_category= Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_id)?>
     <?php if($_category->getId()):?> 
    <li><a href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_category-
>getName() ?></a>
    </li>
        <?php endif;?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I tried adding this

```
    $_category->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)//get only active 
    categories
```

but it threw an error, I'm not a great php guy, I just find pieces of code and try to make them work. I got the original parts from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39340166/magento-show-categories-a-product-is-in)

as per below I've tried to add in the code that follows but I'm still seeing categories listed that are not active...

```
<ul class="listfix">
<?php $activeCategories = 
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
->getColumnValues('entity_id');
?>  

<?php $activeCategories = $_product->getCategoryIds(); ?>
<?php foreach($activeCategories as $k => $_category_id):  ?>
<?php $_category= Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category_id)?>
    <?php if($_category->getId()):?> 
<li><a href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_category-
>getName() ?></a>
</li>
    <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: First, one will need to know what version of Magento you're running ..

Comment: its 1.9.1.0 on php 5.6.30

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a list of all the active Categor ID's in 1.9:

```
$activeCategories = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
->getColumnValues('entity_id');
```

Then you loop through that array, and load the category, or whatever, by ID:

```
foreach($activeCategories as $id) {
  $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
}
```

Comment: tried editing my code to use this loop, it somehow made a category that wasn't associated with that product show up on the product page.

Comment: in your code, you need to compare `$categories` to `$activeCategories` --  if the category id from `$categories` exists in $`activeCategories` then display it -- Else, skip

Comment: I posted your code that I added into the original question, I am still seeing categories that aren't active.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="listmem">
<?php $activeCategories = 
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
->getColumnValues('entity_id');?>

<ul class="listfix">
<?php $activeCategories = $_product->getCategoryIds(); ?>
<?php foreach($activeCategories as $id) {
    $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
} ?>

<?php if($cat->getId()):?> 
    <li><a href="<?php echo $cat->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $cat->getName() ?>
</a>
    </li>
<?php endif;?>
</ul>
```

I thought I sorted out what I was doing wrong, but I'm still seeing the categories that aren't active in my list.

Comment: just noticed this code was throwing error if the product didnt' belong to any category so I had to go back to my original